# Preserving DatetimeIndex `freq` in MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `pd.DatetimeIndex` with a `freq` which I want to use as part of a `pd.MultiIndex`, but when I do so the freq gets set to `None`. Can I preserve the freq?

```
[1]: dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-03-31', freq='M')
     labls = pd.Index(['AA','BB'])
     multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, labls])
```

As expected, `dates` has a monthly `freq='M'`:

```
[2]: dates
[2]: DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-31', '2000-02-29', '2000-03-31'],
        dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Level 0 in the multi-index is a DatetimeIndex, but the freq is `None`, presumably due to the repeated values.

```
[3]: multi.get_level_values(0)
[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-31', '2000-01-31', '2000-02-29', '2000-02-29',
               '2000-03-31', '2000-03-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Is there any way to recover the freq that went in?

PS: I see that if you use `pd.PeriodIndex` instead of DatetimeIndex, then the freq *is* preserved.

Unfortunately PeriodIndex won't work for me, since I use both month-start (MS) and month-end (M) frequencies with DatetimeIndex, and they're not differentiated in PeriodIndex.

Comment: I dont think it should lose the frequency. maybe raise it as a bug on the pandas github page